# Running C# MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I was using my own computer with VS 2015 installed in it. When I run / played my Index.cshtml, it would run into URL 
`http://localhost:xxxx/Controller/Index`
and it would run fine.

But then after my company told me to use their computer with VS 2012 instead, When I run / played my Index.cshtml, it would run into URL
`http://localhost:xxxx/Views/Controller/Index.cshtml`, then it would show error about cant find the right path.

what am I missing in my project? I tried to remove and re-add System.Web.MVC into my references, but it still the same. I have spent a lot of time try to fix it, but cant find the answer yet.

Or do I need to install some add-on into my VS?

**EDIT

sorry if I make you misunderstand my question. My question is, how to make my `VS 2012` can run into the same `URL` with my `VS 2015` automatically. because right now, each time I run my project in VS 2012, I need to edit my URL manually so that it could run into the right path and URL

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to @Fedri Qrueger that I able to find the answer. Even after Installing the extension, the problem still occurs.

the solution that I found is to edit to project.

Right click on project => properties => web

Then change start action from **Current Page** into **Specific Page**, and leave it blank. as it answered in [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1954235.aspx?start%20page%20when%20debugging%20a%20mvc%20app%20works%20fine%20from%20model%20and%20controller%20breaks%20starting%20debugging%20from%20view)

Answer (score 1):

if you create mvc project on vs 2015 there is a possibility you create a MVC 5 project that not have built in support on vs 2012. you need to install the extension.

The stand alone installer is located here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532

The release/installation notes can be found at

http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2012/aspnet-and-web-tools-20131-for-visual-studio-2012

Dependency:

- .NET 4.5

Included:

- MVC5
- Entity Framework 6
- Web API 2
- Bootstrap
- Razor
- Nuget 2.7

Comment: after I checked My VS 2012, I realized that I have installed that extension. But thank to you that I got more meta keyword to able to search more about the problems